# Open Postfix or Sendmail to all IP's

Tags: postfix, smtp

Can I configure Postfix or Sendmail to allow all IP's without authentication?  I understand that this could lead to all sorts of abuse.  We have some monitoring systems that send notifications out via an SMTP server but it doesn't support authentication so I plan on telling the firewall to allow only that IP to connect.

Thanks

Comment: What is the IP address(es) of your MTA?

Comment: nice try to get the address of an open relay. ;)

Comment: Yeahhhh... I wasn't falling for that one ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't open postfix for everyone.

You can allow relay access to one address (or network) with the following line in your main.cf

`mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yy`

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx => the address you want to permit
yy => the netmask of your host (or network)

Comment: Thanks for this.  It turns out I was having issues testing due to AWS blocking some outgoing ports, but this would have done what I asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure specific ip-adresses to use your postfix or sendmail installation as an outgoing SMTP server or relay host without SMTP authentication, which is much better idea.

In sendmail that is configured with the access map, typically /etc/mail/access:

```
Connect:127.0.0.1         RELAY
Connect:10.9.8.7          RELAY
Connect:192.168.1         RELAY
```

Which allows relaying for localhost (the default), the IP-addres 10.9.8.7 and the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.